# Auth0 Authorization Code Flow with custom login page

Tags: auth0, auth0-lock

Is it possible to use Auth0 Authorization Code Flow without Auth0 lock (widget)?

Auth0 */authorize* endpoint always redirects to auth0 lock, can it redirect to custom login page?

Comment: In auth0 Hosted login page, you should be able to enable custom login page. https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/when-to-use-lock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer**: Auth0 is not suitable for custom login page.

**Long Answer:**
The only solution provided by Auth0 is embedded login for web, but it has security issues and hard to setup. Quoting from their [website](https://auth0.com/docs/login/embedded):

> There are security concerns with this approach, particularly if you do not use the [Custom Domains](https://auth0.com/docs/custom-domains) feature at Auth0, as this potentially opens your application up to [cross-origin authentication](https://auth0.com/docs/cross-origin-authentication) issues.

In fact, Chrome is going to disable cross-origin authentication attempts in the future:
https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches/

Quoting Again from *Chromium‎ > ‎Chromium Security‎ > ‎
Changes to Cross-Origin Requests in Chrome Extension Content Scripts*

> tl;dr: To improve security, cross-origin fetches will soon be disallowed from content scripts in Chrome Extensions.  Such requests can be made from extension background pages instead, and relayed to content scripts when needed.